# Unable to pass SOQL response as a param to another same class method in APEX lightning

Tags: apex, soql, lightning, aura, salesforce-id

```
    List<Liabilities__c> al=new List<Liabilities__c>();
    al=[Select Liability_Balance__c,Liability_Months_Left__c from Liabilities__c Where Applicant__c=:borrower];
    for(Liabilities__c alc:al){
        listOfBLiability.add(getBorrowerLiabilities(alc));
    }
```

and the method as like below

```
@AuraEnabled
public static BorrowerLiabilityItem getBorrowerLiabilities(Liabilities__c al){
        BorrowerLiabilityItem bLI=new BorrowerLiabilityItem();
        bLI.mapModel(al);
        return bLI;
}
```

Its giving me the error like

> Line: 17, Column: 31
>   Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void getBorrowerAssets(Liabilities__c) from the type anon

Please help me out in this.Thanq

Comment: Static method should be called with class name: `ClassName.method()`. So it should be accessed as `BorrowerLiabilityItem.getBorrowerLiabilities(alc);`.

Comment: Seems there is a conflict between your calling method and method in error.
you are calling getBorrowerLiabilities(alc) but the error says this method has wrong syntax `getBorrowerAssets(Liabilities__c)`
also, I second @Raul, you should be using ClassName.method() for static methods.

Comment: Both in same class ,both methods are static only,in that case also do we need to mention class name.method name!